# Fetch data from database and display to a textbox using php and ajax

Tags: php, ajax

I'm creating a small project using php and jax, when I fetch data to database and display to a textbox using specific variable declared in may query it is working but when I try to use declared variable it is not working. 
For example:

`SELECT remaining FROM sys_stocks WHERE particulars='MONITOR' - Working Fine.`

`$particularslogs = $_POST['particularslogs'];
SELECT remaining FROM sys_stocks WHERE particulars='$particularslogs'` - Not Working

What should be the problem?

Thank you in advance.

Here's what I tried so far.

PHP Code.

```
<?php
include_once('../connection/pdo_db_connection.php');

$particularslogs = $_POST['particularslogs'];

$database = new Connection();
$db = $database->open();

$query = $db->prepare("SELECT remaining FROM sys_stocks WHERE  
particulars='$particularslogs'");
$query->execute();
$query->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

while ($row = $query->fetch()) {
    echo $row['remaining'];
}

//close connection
$database->close();
?>
```

AJAX Code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#stocksdatelogs').on('blur', function(){
 $.ajax({
 type    : "get",
 url     : 'function/remaining_stocks_fetch.php',      
 success : function(remaining)
   {
     $('#remaininglogs').val(remaining);
   }
  });
 });
</script>
```

I expect the output will display the MONITOR remaining count into my database table which is 5 to a remaining textbox field using WHERE particulars='$particularslogs' and not WHERE particulars='MONITOR'.

Comment: Bobby Tables https://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: In your ajax code you're doing a GET request with no params, and in your php you're getting the variable from $_POST which is for POST requests.

Answer (score 0):

You are not sending the data.

1 - send the data from ajax method to php file something like this.

```
url     : 'function/remaining_stocks_fetch.php',
data: {particularslogs: your data field name},
```

2- You are using GET method so you need to change the method POST to GET, something like this.

```
$particularslogs = $_GET['particularslogs'];
```

OR

Change the type var in the ajax method, like this.

```
type    : "POST",
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I've already tried it but still not working. How about async false in ajax. I've read in many articles about it and they say variable can't read by ajax?

Comment: Hi Rahul Shrivastava, I already solved my problem now by changing this line:      
 data    : {particularslogs:remaining},                                                                           
 to this line:                                                                                         
 particularslogs: $("#particularslogs").val(),                                                                  Thanks a lot.

Comment: @KenjiroAikawa great.